# Alterar tempo de tarefa no Windows

Tags: windows, script, agendamento

Preciso configurar uma tarefa do Windows para que a mesma seja executada de 30 em 30 segundos, porém o agendador de tarefas possui como tempo mínimo de 1 minuto e se tento alterar para (30 segundos || 0.5 minutos || 0,5 minutos) sempre me é exibida a mesma mensagem de erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se souberem algum modo de resolver isso, quem sabe algum script onde eu possa determinar algum intervalo de tempo entre uma execução e outra ou talvez algum modo de realizar uma configuração avançada quem sabe.

Comment: A pergunta faz sim parte do escopo do site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meu conselho pra você é: **crie um serviço do Windows**, é pra isso que eles servem.

No agendador de tarefas do Windows é impossível criar disparadores com menos de 1 minuto de repetição.

Em contrapartida, é possível definir múltiplos disparadores. Para você conseguir rodar sua tarefa a cada 30 segundos, vai precisar de dois disparadores que repitam a cada 1 segundo, onde um deles comece as **X horas** e outro comece 30 segundos **após as X horas**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Foi exatamente isso que eu encontrei aqui: https://superuser.com/questions/293445/windows-task-scheduler-schedule-task-to-run-once-every-10-seconds/668074#668074 Obrigado pela dica +1